# Android fastest possible way for service to send data to Activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-broadcast

I am working on a project, where an Arduino sends a constant stream of data to Android via Bluetooth. The data rate was less than desired and I was investigating both Arduino and Android program to find the bottleneck and this is what I found.
I think the bottleneck is in the communication between android Bluetooth service and the activity. I am using a local broadcast to send data from Service to Activity and I noticed that the broadcasts are keep coming to Activity even after Arduino stop sending data. Because of this, I concluded that the bottleneck has to be in the way that my Bluetooth service is sending data to the activity.

At first, I was using a broadcast manager, then I switched to the local broadcast manager and saw some improvement but nothing groundbreaking. I was wondering if anyone knows the fastest way possible for me to send data from Service to Activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of method. 
I recommend using Intend because it is very easy

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity{
    private MyBroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public static final String ACTION = "com.example.ACTION_SOMETHING"
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String test = intent.getStringExtra("dataToPass");
        }
    }
}
```

send to activity in service class

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(SomeActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
intent.putExtra("dataToPass", test);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that would probably help. I ended up doing something else, however. I started a asyncTask in my activity that keeps calling a method in my class to see if there is available data. This ended up boosting my performance more than 10 times. Do you think there is a negative side to my method ?